# Problem with Javascript on Product View Page

Tags: javascript

I've installed the Ultimo theme and it works great but there is a javascript error on the product view page which effects the dropdown navigation, image zoom and tabs for the product description, reviews etc,etc.

I have no idea how to debug the problem to fix it.
Example = <strike>http://goo.gl/uajKTY</strike>

Comment: Try posting a ticket to theme company or disabling extensions that have jquery involved

Answer (score 6):

I have checked view source of your page.

There are two jQuery files included in your page.

They are

i) http://www.handcoded.co.uk/berserks/js/infortis/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

ii) //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js

Try removing one. That may solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I hadn't spotted that.The page now works correctly.

Comment: @user1503887, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.  Thanks!